# Django-Javascript : best way to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a contact form in my page. When it is submitted, a ajax function is called.

This function get the name of recipient. For this, it split the id of form submitted.
(The id of form is like this : formsubmitted_NAME-OF-RECIPIENT)

For example :

`var name_recipient = $("form[name='form_submitted']").attr('id').split("_")[1];`

When I have this name, I send it to my view Django and my view sends the message to the user with this name sended by Ajax.

The problem is that I am not sure is good secure. I am affraid that a "hacker" can handles this function Ajax and he changes the name of recipient.

But I don't have others solutions... What do you think about my apprehension ?

Comment: you should use sended use from server side rather then from client side sending with in ajax data.

Comment: I know but the advantage of Ajax is that I don't change page. Else I must create a new html (and new url and view) for send message to user...

Comment: Use ajax call but in your ajax URL server side method you have to pass user from login `session` not from ajax send data. So no one can send their on username. Users info setted by login user session data.

Comment: Yes, it's correct for the sender but the recipient isn't ncessarily logged.

Answer (score 0):

Always rely on server side scripting for validation. 
On client side, data can be edited.
The image below shows how to edit ajax data.[!Web developer tools in Mozilla firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1fB.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1fB.png)

Comment: So, It's better I create a new view (and new url) just for this contact form ??

Answer (score 0):

To protect your forms, django includes csrf protection middleware per default in the settings.py , so in the beginning of the form in the template file you just add the following template tag {% csrf_token %} and then you don't worry about any hacking risk around your form. For more info [check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)

Comment: But with csrf protection, the "hacker" can always modify my ajax function

Comment: I don't see how he can do something like that. It sounds unrealistic. What would be his execution plan if the action is possible.